# How to fix error applying a round function in columns of a dataset (SparkException: Task not serializable)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I'm start using Spark with Scala in the dataBricks notebook, however I'm having an odd error:

```
 SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, value: t020101)
- writeObject data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
- object (class scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy, scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy@1ccc6944)
- writeReplace data (class: scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy)
 ...
```

The code works fine when I do the round function directly on the values:

```
 def timeUsageGroupedRound(summed: Dataset[TimeUsageRow]): Dataset[TimeUsageRow] = {

  summed.map{
       case TimeUsageRow(working, sex, age, primaryNeeds, work, other) => 
       TimeUsageRow(working, sex, age, (primaryNeeds* 10).round / 10d, (work* 10).round / 10d, (other* 10).round / 10d)
     }
   }

 val time_Usage_Round_DS = timeUsageGroupedRound(time_Usage_Grouped_DS)
 display(time_Usage_Round_DS)
```

But, when I try to do an auxiliary function, I got the error mentioned above:

```
 def timeUsageGroupedRound(summed: Dataset[TimeUsageRow]): Dataset[TimeUsageRow] = {

  def round1(d:Double):Double = (d * 10).round / 10d

  summed.map{
       case TimeUsageRow(working, sex, age, primaryNeeds, work, other) => 
       TimeUsageRow(working, sex, age, round1(primaryNeeds), round1(work), round1(other))
     }
   }
 val time_Usage_Round_DS = timeUsageGroupedRound(time_Usage_Grouped_DS)
 display(time_Usage_Round_DS)
```

Does anyone can explain why this happen? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer 1:**

Move the `round1` out of your class and into an object (perhaps use a companion object https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html).

**Short answer 2:**

Alternatively, move whatever is not `Serializable` outside of your class (see Long answer) - though this might be painful depending on the size of the class.

**Long answer:**

This is an interesting one which has tripped me up a few times in the past. Firstly, when you do .map on a Dataset/DataFrame, what's happening under the hood is that everything inside the map - in your case:

```
case TimeUsageRow(working, sex, age, primaryNeeds, work, other) => 
   TimeUsageRow(working, sex, age, round1(primaryNeeds), round1(work), round1(other))
```

is packaged up and sent from the driver to the executors. Because of the way Spark communicates between driver and executor, everything you send needs to be `Serializable`. This error is occurring because when `round1` is included, it also drags in the rest of the class with it, and if there is something sitting in the class which is not `Serializable`, then this error comes up.